# Designing a way to audit changes to tables

Tags: .net, sql-server, audit

I want to be able to audit activity that is performed on db tables (updates, inserts etc). What would be the most effective way to design this? One solution I have in mind is to have a audit table for every table and use SQL triggers to do a insert the previous value before the table is updated with a new value.

Comment: If you need to keep historic records, a better approach would be "soft delete". the point is you never update and never delete records, instead you insert new records and mark the older ones as deleted (using a datetime2 to keep delete date).

Comment: Triggers are the traditional standard way to implement data-auditing, and IMHO, one of the few correct use-cases for triggers.  However, in later versions of SQL Server, there are also a variety of administrative tools for doing this also that are probably preferable, in particular, the "Database Audits" feature. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/cc280386.aspx

Comment: if you already creates your own triggers "use SQL triggers to do a insert the previous value before the table is updated with a new value." then why not use them for this? By the way, triggers are great tools but they need to be used very carefully. they might reduce the performance significantly in some cases.

Comment: SQL Server does not include a built-in BEFORE triggers but only AFTER and INSTEAD OF triggers (i am talking about DML triggers since there are other types). Therefore, If you want to implement BEFORE trigger then you can use INSTEAD of trigger.

Comment: CodeSmith can be great for creating all these triggers and history tables.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server from version 2008 include a built-in option for what you are looking for. It named CDC or Change Data Capture. You can get more information in the BOL (officially Book-On-Line) in the first link or from the blog in the sec link:

- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489(v=sql.105).aspx
- https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/introduction-to-change-data-capture-(cdc)-in-sql-server-2008/

There are other options as well that you can use. but in order to choose the best option for you we need more information on your system. It will help if (1) you can describe your system architecture, and (2) what information do you want to store in your auditing (do you need the user name or just audit the data it self), (3) do you need to keep history or only get the events, (4) is this temporary needs or part of the database structure (CDC will create elements like triggers and is not fits for temporary audit, for this you better use extended event or profiler). CDC is very good option for audit data changes, if it fits your needs.

Comment: I approve your edit @Ubaidullah Khan, but I think that it was a mistake actually :-(. You just remove the opening "Good Day" from my answer, I do not see any problem with starting polite with "Good day" blessing. I am new here. I registered long time ago, but almost never came here. I came here to support in this interface two days ago by mistake. I still did not got to a decision if I will add this to the list of forums that I supports at. any way I got the message regarding your edit and just approved it :-)

Comment: there is nothing wrong with it (in my opinion), but it's not very "stackoverflow spirit"... [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

Comment: Do you need the enterprice version to use Change Data Capture?

Comment: Yes @Ian Ringrose, it is only Enterprise Enterprise: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(en-us,SQL.100).aspx

Comment: @zohar-peled, well.. as I said, I need to come a decision if the website approach fits me. at this time, this is not look like it is, in first glance. at this time I get the feeling that this is Q&A interface (only the Q and final answer are matter), and this does not fits with my approach which is to help only to people that want to learn.

Comment: I have no intention to work for free for people that just look for someone that will make their "home work". My approach is to help to people that want to learn, and for this we need to teach, and not just give final answer. We need discussion, and yesterday someone left the answer (my answer), but deleted all the discussion part. I did not lost points, but i feel that I wasted time to help, since other people will not see all the comments and discussion, and will just use the final answer.

Comment: @Ronen: Yes, it's not like a forum or blog where a dialog is encouraged. I guess it doesn't suit everybody. you can't really use this as a tutorial platform like you are used to from 'tapuz'... However, I believe that it is a good platform to spread your knowledge once you get used to the rules of the house (I also find some of them annoying, though)...

Comment: This is definitely only a Q&A site. Please take the time to read the [help]. If you need to have discussions in order to help people, then you're in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

For the application side, I would look at ORMs to help you with this, if you are still in the design stage. I would look and limiting as much as possible, users having access to the raw data tables.

- [Nhibernate Versioning](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/lesser-known-nhibernate-features-versioning-and-optimistic-concurrency)
- [Entity Framework Audit Log](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended#audit-log)

FYI, depending on your situation this may be at too high of a level, since you may want to keep tabs on every change that someone makes in the DB with any tool.

Comment: **This is very bad option to monitor the data, since you have no control on data that was changed outside your application.** several years ago, i serve a company that used complex CMS application. The CEO was sure that he understand what he is doing, and was deleting data from time to time, directly from the server. It caused the application to crash (he alway lie and say that he did not do anything). Once I added some limitation in the database level, this could not happen again :-)

Comment: This fit if you want to monitor the application :-)

Comment: @RonenAriely Which is why I included the FYI part on the bottom. It really depends on how many stupid people have too deep of access to the data. :-D

Comment: @jbg: "Programming today is a race between software engineers striving to build bigger and better idiot-proof programs, and the Universe trying to produce bigger and better idiots. So far, the Universe is winning." [Rick Cook](http://www.quotationspage.com/quotes/Rick_Cook/)

Comment: @ZoharPeled LOL, so very true

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server, from version 2008, also includes [SQL Server Audit](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386.aspx). There are database-level audit actions that enable you to audit those operations on tables. (Please note that database-level auditing is available only on Enterprise and Developer versions. See blog on [SQL Server Audit Support in Different Editions and Versions](https://www.logbinder.com/Blog/?p=d1f5efd3-d0a8-4c3e-82a5-6c8fc7e7f672).)